# Aggregation of XML elements (sum, grouping and unique values)

Tags: xquery

I am new in xquery. Can you please suggest xquery to get the below output xml.

Input xml :

```
<elem count="4" name="ABC">
   <elem count="3" name="VAl_1">
   <elem count="1" name="VAl_2">
</elem>
<elem count="5" name="PQR">
   <elem count="2" name="VAl_1">
   <elem count="3" name="Val_3">
</elem>
```

Output xml:

```
<elem count="9" name="ABC,PQR">
   <elem count="5" name="VAl_1">
   <elem count="1" name="VAl_2">
   <elem count="3" name="VAl_3">
</elem>
```

I have parent node with count and name as attr. When I combine the parent node. count values should get added for parent as well as for children if they having same name.

This should be done in recursive way for any no of parents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few assumptions, but the following solves at least the problem as stated:

```
declare variable $input :=
   <input>
      <elem count="4" name="ABC">
         <elem count="3" name="VAl_1"/>
         <elem count="1" name="VAl_2"/>
       </elem>
      <elem count="5" name="PQR">
         <elem count="2" name="VAl_1"/>
         <elem count="3" name="Val_3"/>
       </elem>
   </input>/*;

<elem count="{ sum($input/@count) }"
      name="{ string-join(distinct-values($input/@name), ',') }">
{
   for $name in distinct-values($input/elem/@name)
   let $grp  := $input/elem[@name eq $name]
   return
      <elem count="{ sum($grp/@count) }" name="{ $name }"/>
}
</elem>
```

The first half of the code is just declaring a variable with the example input.  The query itself is an element template using simple `sum()` and `distinct-values()` call to provision both attributes.

The interesting part is the `for` loop.  By looping over distinct values for `@name`, then for each of them selecting all `elem` with the same value, it actually makes a grouping of the `elem`s using the key `@name`.

Comment: It would be awesome if you would explain what your code does and what your though-process was, so the OP and others can benefit not just from one code snippet, but instead learning how to "think in XQuery".

Comment: Hey Florent Georges,
Thanks a lot :)

Actually I am working on a search engine which returns a XML result set along with the faceted results. Facet is nothing but the count for particular value within the result set.
Requirement was I should combine the result count as per the user provided names.

Comment: Thank you @dirkk. I thought it was simple enough, but at least the grouping was worth explaining.

Comment: @Aniket, if you need the example to be adapted (if the answer does not really answer your question), please adapt your question accordingly.